# SQL to merge groups of data that share a record

Tags: sql, merge

Looking for sql to merge groups of data into a single label if they share any record.
In

```
Label|Record
1|A
1|B
1|C
2|B
2|D
3|D
3|E
4|F
4|G
4|H
```

Out

```
100|A
100|B
100|C
100|D
100|E
200|F
200|G
200|H
```

Since label 1 shares B with label 2 and label 2 shares D with label 3, they should all end up under the same label. For my purposes the resulting labels don't matter as long as they are different. Having the output labels be 1 & 4 or 3 &4 is fine.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  This requires support for recursive CTEs or hierarchical queries -- if you want to do this in a single statement.  Not all databases support that functionality; those that do have slightly different functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Original Poster here. (I created a second account by mistake). the database being used is spark-sql.